# Internal and External ChangeEvent (JSlider w/Change Listener)

Tags: java, swing

As far as I can determine, if I add a `ChangeListener` to a `JSlider` component, then a `ChangeEvent` event is fired whether the aforementioned slider has its value changed either internally by the program or externally by the user through the GUI.

Is there a way to only have the `ChangeListener` recognize external changes to the `JSlider`'s value?  That is, I want to be able to internally set the value of the slider multiple times throughout the course of the program without having an event fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to keep a flag in your listener which indicates whether the received event is externally triggered or not.

When you change the value, you first update the value of the flag, avoiding that your listener reacts on the changes you just made. Afterwards, you restore the state of the flag.

Comment: I suppose this will work, but was hoping for a way to more easily differentiate the source of the event.

Answer (score 1):

You are always going to fire a `ChangeEvent` whether you change the `JSlider` value internally or externally. You could always have a class member variable to indicate from where the change is being made...